# Can I format an Excel column to be a hyperlink based on the text I enter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a bunch of hyperlinks that only vary by a number at the end, such as:

```
https://somesite.com/but/the_URL_is&20%QUITE_LONG/query?1234
https://somesite.com/but/the_URL_is&20%QUITE_LONG/query?9876
https://somesite.com/but/the_URL_is&20%QUITE_LONG/query?57483
https://somesite.com/but/the_URL_is&20%QUITE_LONG/query?13543
```

Is there a way to apply formatting to the column so that I only have to put in the number for the cell value, (1234) and it formats it to be a hyperlink to the URL?

Comment: You can format it to look like a hyperlink, but I don't think you can create an actual hyperlink with format alone. The creation of a hyperlink could be achieved with HYPERLINK in a helper column, or with VBA perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you want to show in your display (the long URL or just the number). Here's a way to do both:

Cell C2 formula:

```
    =HYPERLINK(CONCAT($A$2,B2))
```

Or if you want to show just the number, then add a friendly name in the formula, such as cell C6 formula:

```
    =HYPERLINK(CONCAT($A$2,B6),B6)
```

[image]

***Edit***
After posting, I just realized you asked if you could "format". I guess my answer is not sufficient and I could therefore remove it if it does not address your question.